# the noun form of 'we are under the department of XXX'

Tags: nouns

The meaning I want to deliver is:

`We need to tell the school that we are from the department of education when we approach them.`

But since I want to present it in a proper way, I plan to write something like below:

`Staff members are reminded to clearly state their affiliation with the department of education while having phone conversation.`

I think `affiliation with the department of education` is not the right phrase, any better suggestion?

Comment: Yes, "staff members" are not "affiliates."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Staff members are reminded to clearly state their connection with the Department of Education in the course of any phone conversation with [an interlocutor]".